# How to adjust spaces between justified words in Word by VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to better arrange justified paragraphs in Word.

When justifying a paragraph, often there is too much space between the words.

For short texts, I visually look for the "ugly" lines, select them and use small macros (one or more times) like this:

```vb
Sub spacingMinus005()
    With Selection.Font
        If .Spacing >= 10 Then
            .Spacing = -0.05
        Else
            .Spacing = .Spacing - 0.05
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

For long documents, it's too laborious.
I would like a script which scans the text by measuring the apparent spaces between the justified words and which highlights these words. **I can't find a function to measure these apparent spaces.**
With this function, it won't be difficult to write a cycle that goes through these ugly lines by gradually shrinking them, like in my macro.

I tried the following functions, native in Word:

- [automatic hyphenation](https://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_automatic_hyphenation.html): very good but insufficient
- ["WordPerfect justification"](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T005984_Better-Looking_Full_Justification_for_Paragraphs.html) option in compatibility mode: insufficient and absent in recent files without compatibility mode

Comment: "I can't find the function to measure these apparent spaces." - That's because there isn't one. Using VBA, you can only automate what is available in the UI. As the UI doesn't have a function to do what you require, neither does VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only workable way to fix this problem is to change each document to Word 2010 compatibility mode, then apply the WordPerfect Justification settings and save. Here's a macro to do that:

```
Sub BetterJustification()
    With ActiveDocument
        .SetCompatibilityMode wdWord2010
        .Compatibility(wdWPJustification) = True
        .SaveAs2 CompatibilityMode:=14
    End With
End Sub
```

Please note that by default, Word's Save As command will try to upsave to the current Word format, which will reset the justification to Microsoft's crappy settings. To prevent this, Word's Save As dialog needs to have the option checked for **Maintain compatibility with previous versions of Word**. This is a sticky setting that remains the same for all files until a user unchecks it. I haven't found a way to check that box using VBA.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This solution makes the job easier. It is indeed a pity if Word is not capable of a better adjustment. 
On the other hand, don't you have a well-placed friend at Microsoft to support [this request](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/db09ea2b-c515-ee11-a81c-000d3a7a48db)? :)
Thank you and have a nice day.